# jQuery Google Charting - changing series data

Tags: jquery, charts

I am sure there is a simple solution to this but I can't seem to get it working.

I need to change the series data for my chart:

This works (in my function):

```
var data = [$.gchart.series('title1', [50], '#F5B800'), 
            $.gchart.series('title2', [40], 'red')]; 

$('#chart').gchart('change', {series: data});
```

but I would like to set the series values dynamically from a passed value:

(ex)

```
value1 = '[70]';

var data = [$.gchart.series('title1', value1, '#F5B800'), 
            $.gchart.series('title2', [40], 'red')]; 

$('#chart').gchart('change', {series: data});
```

This causes a js error and the chart does not render.

I've tried a number of combinations without any success.

Any ideas?

Comment: indent code 4 spaces so that it looks like code. i've edited your post  to do that.

Comment: Anyone? Maybe this is not as simple as I thought.

Comment: I figured it out. You simply need to define a js array (in my case a single dimension) and set the array value to your series value. Then replace [40] in my example with your js array an it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
value1 = "70";
var data = [$.gchart.series('title1', (value1), '#F5B800'), 
            $.gchart.series('title2', [40], 'red')]; 

$('#chart').gchart('change', {series: data});
```